# Magento Dispatching events in templates

Tags: php, event-observer, template

**Hello World, I will jump right into it..**

**Desired Logic**

I would like my template to dispatch an event every time the user clicks the
on and off buttons.
My view.phtml file look likes this...

```
/*Some Html*/ 


<?php
/*=== Variables ===========*/
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/*$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();*/
$groupId = $customer->getGroupId();
$group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
$groupCode = $group->getCode();

$OnArray = array(
   "value" => "on", 
   "customer" => $customer
    );
$OffArray = array(
   "value" => "off", 
   "customer" => $customer
    );
?>

  /* More HTML * /  

<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="auto-refill" value="On" onClick = "<?php Mage: dispatchEvent('autoFill_Update', $OnArray ?>" />On<br>
    <input type="radio" name="auto-refill" value="Off" onClick = "<?php Mage: dispatchEvent('autoFill_Update', $OffArray ?>" />Off
</form>
```

**Update**
Based on the answers and comments I updated my template code..
I am still having trouble calling the controller from the view..
**Code Update**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function autoRefillController(){
           new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('Autorefill/CustomerGroup/updateCustomerGroup') ?>", {
               method: 'post',
            //   parameters: {parameter_name:value},
               onSuccess: function(transport) {

                   //alert(transport.responseText);
                   alert('response for ON received');
               }
           });
       }
</script>

<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="auto-refill" value="On" onClick = "autoRefillController()"/>On<br>
    <input type="radio" name="auto-refill" value="Off" onClick="dispatchCustomEvent()"/>Off
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function dispatchCustomEvent() {
    //data.eventName = event;

    //new Ajax.Request('module/controller/action', {
    new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('Autorefill/CustomerGroup/updateCustomerGroup') ?>", {
        method: 'post',
        //parameters: data,
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            alert('response for OFF received');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**Questions**
Did I access my controller correctly?

**Any guidance is truly appreciated**

Comment: why dont you just use ajax for this?..

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the use cases for the Magento event/observer system. Registering and triggering events with `Mage::dispatchEvent` is typically reserved for *server-side* activities, prior to the output/rendering process.

Judging by your sample code, the `onClick` assignment will do nothing on click, as you're executing PHP code at run-time and it will **not** run when the element is clicked by the user.

Look into using *JavaScript* events instead:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event
- http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/

Where the click handler might look like this instead:

```
onClick="dispatchCustomEvent('autoFill_Update', <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($data)) ?>;"
```

Where `dispatchCustomEvent` might look like this:

```
function dispatchCustomEvent(event, data) {
    data.eventName = event;

    new Ajax.Request('module/controller/action', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: data,
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            alert('response received');
        }
    });
}
```

Where `module/controller/action` is the endpoint in Magento to match your controller to receive this event and do something with the event data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still can not access my controller............Is my ajax request logic correct ?             Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('Autorefill/CustomerGroup/updateCustomerGroup') ?>"

Comment: I'm not sure. If you could post your module's config.xml, I could get a better idea. A snippet of the controller class would help, too. <-- though this might be more well suited as a separate question (else research controller setups yourself).

For starters, the `module/controller` part of the route should be lowercase, while the `action` part should match the controller's method name exactly. If the controller's method is `updatesomeThingAction` then the `action` part of the route would be `updatesomeThing`.

Answer (score 0):

you would like to do somethings when user click the on or off button, so, dispatch event is not better for this case, so just hit an ajax call when user click the on or off button,then in controller method do whatever you want based on the user request..